# Dividing Two Data Frames (One into the Other) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, division

How would I divide one data frame by another? The two data frames have the same columns and same rows, but I need to divide every intersect with its corresponding intersect into a new data frame, e.g. below:

```
DF1
Name    Jan    Feb    Mar
Aaron     2      4      3
Blake     5      6      4

DF2
Name    Jan    Feb    Mar
Aaron     4      6      6
Blake     7      6      5

DF1/DF2 = DF3

DF3 (result)
Name    Jan    Feb    Mar
Aaron   0.5    0.7    0.5
Blake   0.7    1.0    0.8
```

I'm using subset then dcast to build each data frame, but having a hard time figuring out how to divide them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We divide the numeric columns in both 'DF1' and 'DF2' (by removing the first column) and `cbind` with the first column.

```
DF3 <- cbind(DF1[1],round(DF1[-1]/DF2[-1],1))
DF3
#    Name Jan Feb Mar
# 1 Aaron 0.5 0.7 0.5
# 2 Blake 0.7 1.0 0.8
```

Comment: Does this work with dataframes with some columns and rows that don't match?

Comment: @user2105555  Here, we are only considering the dimensions to match

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention that you used `subset` and `dcast` to build each data frame, I suspect you have these data already all in one data frame in which case assigning the role of `numerator` and `denominator` might be all you need to do to in order to run the calculation using `ddply`. For instance, going with your example data and melting it back into a long-form data frame, would give you the following with a single `ddply`:

```
# data
DF1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Aaron", "Blake"), Jan = c(2, 5), Feb = c(4, 6), Mar = c(3, 4))
DF2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Aaron", "Blake"), Jan = c(4, 7), Feb = c(6, 6), Mar = c(6, 5))

# long format with 'numerator' and 'denominator' roles assigned
# (unnecessary if you already have long format, just assign numerator/denomninator)
library(reshape2)
df <- rbind(
  transform(
    melt(DF1, id.vars = "Name", variable.name = "Month"),
    role = "numerator"),
  transform(
    melt(DF2, id.vars = "Name", variable.name = "Month"),
    role = "denominator")
)

# ddply 
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Name, Month), summarize, 
      Result = value[role == "numerator"] / value[role == "denominator"])

#   Name Month     Result
# 1 Aaron   Jan 0.5000000
# 2 Aaron   Feb 0.6666667
# 3 Aaron   Mar 0.5000000
# 4 Blake   Jan 0.7142857
# 5 Blake   Feb 1.0000000
# 6 Blake   Mar 0.8000000
```

Comment: +1 that if the data are already in one data.frame, it may be cleaner to calculate the results from that long form.  With your proposed long data.frame `df` and the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages this could also be done as: `df %>%
  spread(role, value) %>%
  mutate(Result = numerator / denominator)`

Comment: Thanks for the effort and education! Always good to see another way to go about it. Thank you!